# Discord py | Как выводить логи удаления и редактирования сообщений в определенный канал

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Discord py** | Как выводить логи удаления и редактирования сообщений в определенный канал
Чтобы пинговало человека старое сообщение и его нынешнюю версию и канал в котором это произошло!
Срочно

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Привет, этот вопрос больше похож на тз для фрилансера, чем на просьбу помочь...  Прикрепите свои попытки решения проблемы, и, возможно, я смогу поправить ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте документацию и всё найдёте.

В [**API Reference**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#messages) есть **`Event`**: **on_message_edit(before, after)** и **on_message_delete(message)**.

***Примеры.***

**on_message_edit**:

```
    async def on_message_edit(before, after):
        print(before.content) #старое сообщение
        print(after.content) #новое сообщение
```

**on_message_delete**:

```
    async def on_message_delete(message):
        print(message.content) #удаленное сообщение
```

Предоставляйте в следующий раз код. Вам никто не собирается писать его за Вас.