# discord py логгер сообщений

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пишу своеобразный журнал аудита на discord.py и столкнулся с проблемой.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отследить удаление или изменение сообщения?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message_delete#discord.on_message_delete

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message_delete#discord.on_message_edit

Answer (score 0):

Раннее отвечал на такой же [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485884/discord-py-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B/1486086#1486086).

В [**API Reference**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#messages) есть **`Event`**: **on_message_edit(before, after)** и **on_message_delete(message)**.

***Примеры.***

**on_message_edit**:

```
    async def on_message_edit(before, after):
        print(before.content) #старое сообщение
        print(after.content) #новое сообщение
```

**on_message_delete**:

```
    async def on_message_delete(message):
        print(message.content) #удаленное сообщение
```